# Can I connect to VirtualBox via an IP address from my parent Windows o/s that has a .net app on it?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, asp.net

I want to run virtual box on my Windows 7 machine in order to connect to a mysql database.

So I have a asp.net application running on the parent/main Windows 7 o/s.

In my VM I want to run Ubuntu, and be able to connect to it via a local IP address.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

you can do so simply pointing the .net application host machine at the ip address if the guest, using host only mode, or bridged networking.

virtual machines arn't all that different, networking wise, from a real machine.

Comment: not sure where to find out the ip of the guest VM?

Comment: ifconfig on the guest should tell you.